# PHP mail function not sending emails to certain addresses

Tags: php, html, email

I've been using the php mail function to send emails containing account details to clients when they are registered but I have only just found out that some people are not receiving emails. E.g. when I send an email to each of my collegues when testing only me and one other collegue are receiving the email

```
- me who received email
- pam@companyx.co.uk
- collegue who received email
- bill@companyx.co.uk
- collegue who did not receive emails:
- email 1 - ted@companyx.co.uk,
- email 2 - ted@companyy.co.uk
- collegue who did not receive emails:
- cal@companyy.co.uk
- collegue who did not receive emails:
- emma@companyy.co.uk
```

The emails are not received in the spam folder either..

```
$from = "companyy <support@companyy.co.uk>";          
$subject = "$username Account Details for companyy.co.uk";     
$message = "You have been registered as an administrator of companyy Online.
You can manage your clients, bills and other account functions online.       

Your Username: $username
Your Password: $password2
Your Four-Digit PIN: $PIN         

Once logged in you can change your password to something you will find easier to remember. Please delete this email once you have changed your settings or memorised them.           

Thank you        

This is an automated response, please do not reply!";

mail($email, $subject, $message, $from);
Header('Location: results.php?msg=Added Successfully');
```

Comment: Even though they don't end up in the spam folder, many points in the answers to "Why do my mails end up in the spam folder" questions (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+spam+mail) apply to this as well. Is this script running on `companyy.co.uk`'s server?

Comment: Check out Jeff Atwoods article on sending email - some non-obvious gotchas there: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: are you using sendmail or what type of mail server?

Comment: am i the only that sees the problem with `$message` not formated correctly? because i am always under the impression it has to be seperated w/ LF and word wrap if its 70 char per line. i am starting to doubt myself because i have never gotten a rep when answering question regarding formatting `$message`, but yet it failes me from time to time when i forget to format

Answer (score 7):

Here's a dirty little secret about sending emails:  you lose control.  Once they've left your server, it's by the grace of the internet gods that your email reaches its destination.  Along the way it "handshakes" from one network to the next.  It reaches its final destination and then is subjected to multitudes of spam filters and rules that many technical people are in the dark on.  For instance, did you know that MSN Hotmail, AOL, etc will not accept more than a certain number of emails from a server (ip range) at once?  Once you hit the server's predetermined (and unpublished) limit, the email will be held regardless of its spam rating.  Eventually it will be let through, but it means that the password request your user does won't be instantaneous.  Here's another tidbit--servers gain "trust" based on longevity of the domain and other factors that are also unpublished.  Has your domain been live long?  Are you listed on a [blacklist](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)?  Is the email "spammy" (check with a tool [like this](http://www.contactology.com/check_mqs.php))

Then there's sites like AOL where even good quality email from good quality servers just doesn't get delivered with regularity. (Google "aol deliverability" for some fun reading)

So, what to do?  Start with blacklist checking.  If that's good, check the headers.  Does the "from" address match the domain the email's being sent from and is that account valid?  That can be a big spam red-flag.  To avoid this problem, my company (who sends 50,000+ emails per day) usually sets up "dummy" reply-to accounts.  Are you in the whitelist for the users you're testing with?  Are the users using a program like Outlook which randomly does its own blacklisting?  Change your message and see if deliverability improves.  Test with multiple different hosts to see if it's just one particular system.

Rinse, repeat, and continue...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the emails are sent. The problems is on the receiving side. Check for spam or for filters. You can log the sent mails to be sure what was sent.

Comment: They'd be in your server's mail server (something like /var/log/mail if you're on a unix-ish system). the PHP `mail()` does not actually send out mail - it just hands it over to the server's mail server to do the delivery. It will *LIE* to you about successful delivery, because it just does a local handoff.

Comment: Just logging what was sent still won't tell you the real truth about whether the delivery was completed.  It just tells what went out the door.  You could BCC yourself to ensure that it's getting through to someone, but that still doesn't answer why one person and not another is getting the email.

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug `$email`, maybe it's empty or bogus:

```
var_dump($email);
```

But this problem is probably not related to php. First of all check some email blacklist site, like http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

If you can't find your box on any blacklist, you have to contact the server administrator, who have to check the out the logs.

Comment: they are not empty or bogus emails because i'm testing using my collegues addresses

Comment: You tried to dump the variable right before the `mail()`? If it's really the correct email address, this problem is not on your side, you have to contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

you may have an ip address that has been blacklisted, common in shared hosting. either move servers or outsource email to sendgrid or postmarkapp

Answer (score 0):

Check your message and make sure it is seperated w/ PHP_EOL

> Message to be sent.
>
> Each line should be separated with a
>   LF (\n). Lines should not be larger
>   than 70 characters.

eg:

```
$message = 'This message was sent via PHP!' . PHP_EOL .
           'It should work ... and it does.' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 
           'From Display Name' . PHP_EOL;
// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
```

When using [PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)